# Need to reinstall a deleted contact

Tags: wordpress

I have accidentally deleted a contact and need to get all their information back, how do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Do you happen to know how it was deleted? Because there's actually two kinds of deleting - one is permanent, one is not.

Try the advanced search and turn on the option to search in the trash.

[image: Search trash]

If they have been permanently deleted, then you won't be able to bring them back in the software - you'll need to find as much of the information elsewhere (backup of your database, emails you got from the system, etc) and manually recreate as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your log_civicrm tables in the database (assuming you have logging turned on) then you should be able to dig out info about a contact who was Deleted (as opposed to just in Trash).

The rows relating to the contact (and related rows in eg log_civicrm_address etc) are not deleted when a contact is actually deleted.